# cert type 4, 5, 7 in cert cell

Tags: torsocks, python, certificate

I'm working on a piece of code that will allow to me connect and pass tcp traffic through socket by implementing the TOR protocol.
I'm currently working on certs cells, and there's a node that gives me cert types of 4, 5 and 7 which are not documented in the tor spec document (only 1, 2, 3 are documented)
Anyone knows what this cert type means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All certificates types are listed [here](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/cert-spec.txt), see section "A.1. List of certificate types"

```
   [04] - Ed25519 signing key with an identity key
          (see prop220 section 4.2)

   [05] - TLS link certificate signed with ed25519 signing key
          (see prop220 section 4.2)

   **[07] - Reserved for RSA identity cross-certification;
          (see section 2.3 above, and tor-spec.txt section 4.2)
```

Comment: In addition, could you please explain the usage of each cert? Im not quit sure I got it right